# Re-using a react component across different routes

Tags: react-router

We ran into a situation where we have edit page and create page sharing the same component. The router looks like below.

```
<Route path="/" component={AdrApp}>
            <IndexRoute component={ManageDrugPage}/>
            <Route path="cdicms-adr-ui" component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path="create-adr" component={ManageADRTermPage}/>
            <Route path="manage-adr/:id" component={ManageADRTermPage}/>
```

As we see above the 'ManageADRTermPage' component is used by 'create-adr' route and 'manage-adr' route.

The problem with this is that we have a dropdown component implemented using react-bootstrap.

When the user is in the edit page and the user now selects the create page the page is not transitioning. The edit page stays right there. we do this.history.pushState(null, '/create-adr') when the 'create' dropdown is clicked.

How could we workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy workaround would be to have a simple CreateADRTermPage component, that's a wrapper for your ManageADRTermPage.

Or change your ManageADRTermPage component to EditADRTerm, and have both CreateADRTermPage and ManageADRTermPage be simple wrappers of it.